# Parse Powermail 2.x Fields HTML in Email Output (TYPO3 6.2.x)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, powermail

In some checkbox fields of a Powermail 2.x form in TYPO3 6.2.x, I have HTML inside the Value of a checkbox, which is needed on the website, but should be "parsed away" in the email to the receiver.

Of the selected value

```
<span class="kurs-col1">Nr.1</span> <span class="kurs-col2">Kurs 1 </span> <span class="kurs-col3">1.1.2015</span>
```

This is the Output I need in the email:

```
Nr.1 Kurs 1 1.1.2015
```

I think I did this in Powermail 1.x with the following TypoScript:

```
label.parse = true
label.allowTags = span,strong
```

But these settings seem to be gone. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I try to edit the mail template `ReceiverMail.html`.

I can strip tags from one field successfully:

```
<f:format.stripTags>
{uid1694}
</f:format.stripTags>
```

But that doesn't work for {powermail_all} yet.

I go to `Partials/PowermailAll/Mail.html` and wrap `<f:format.stripTags></f:format.stripTags>` around the field's value:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top">
    <b><vh:string.RawAndRemoveXss>{answer.field.title}</vh:string.RawAndRemoveXss></b>
</td>
<td valign="top">
    <f:if condition="{vh:Condition.IsArray(val: '{answer.value}')}">
        <f:else>
            <f:format.nl2br><f:format.stripTags>{answer.value}</f:format.stripTags></f:format.nl2br>
        </f:else>
        <f:then>
            <f:for each="{answer.value}" as="subValue" iteration="index">
                <f:if condition="{subValue}">
                    <f:format.stripTags>{subValue}</f:format.stripTags><f:if condition="{index.isLast}"><f:else>, </f:else></f:if>
                </f:if>
            </f:for>
        </f:then>
    </f:if>
</td>
```

And it works, and a big hooray for fluid and Powermail!